# Table View + Protype Cells вывод через тэги

Tags: ios, objective-c, prototype, tableview

Не удается вывести все данные одной персоны в одну ячейку, трудности с индексами :(
В результате получается "Неизвестная" "Санса", а должно быть "Неизвестная" "Персона"

```
// Псевдо таблица
NSArray *person1,*person2;
person1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Неизвестная",@"персона", nil];
person2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Санса",@"Старк", nil];
persons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:person1, person2, nil];
```

Код вывода:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell *c;
c = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"]; // ячейка
UILabel *firstLabel;
//?
if (c == nil) {
    c = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:@"Hmm"];
}
// Передаем выводим через тэг
firstLabel = [c.contentView viewWithTag:1001];
firstLabel.text = [persons[0] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UILabel *secondLabel;
secondLabel = [c.contentView viewWithTag:1002];
secondLabel.text = [persons[1] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return c;
```

}

Label слева имеет тэг 1001,  Label справа тэг 1002 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема вот тут: `secondLabel.text = [persons **[1]** objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` Вы создаете массив, который сожержит в себе два массива: `persons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:person1, person2, nil];`

Далее вы обращаетесь ко второму массиву `persons[1]` и оттуда берете элемент под индексом ячейки `objectAtIndex:indexPath.row`. Чтобы получить  "Неизвестная" "Персона" Вам надо обратиться к первому массиву и получить оттуда второй элемент: `secondLabel.text = [persons[0] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row + 1];`

В данный момент Ваш массив `persons` выглядит так: `persons = [[Неизвестная][персона],[Санса][Старк]];`, где `[Неизвестная][персона]` имеют индексы `[00][01]` и `[Санса][Старк] [10][11]`;

Comment: Спасибо, а как использовать indexPath в роли индекса?
В таком варианты программа падает

    int firstIndex = indexPath;
    int secondIndex = 0;
    UILabel *firstLabel;
    firstLabel = [c.contentView viewWithTag:1001];
    firstLabel.text = persons[firstIndex][secondIndex];
    secondIndex++;
    UILabel *secondLabel;
    secondLabel = [c.contentView viewWithTag:1002];
    secondLabel.text = persons[firstIndex][secondIndex];

Comment: indexPath имеет два значения - секцию и ячейкy. Так делать нельзя: `int firstIndex = indexPath`, Нужно: `int firstIndex = indexPath.row` или `int firstIndex = indexPath.section` все зависит от того, что вам надо, но судя по вашей таблице у вас всего одна секция.